# Launcher doesn't respond and acts oddly

Tags: unity, launcher, transmission

I have recently downloaded the 12.04 Ubuntu version and decided to try using Ubuntu after hearing many good things about it. So far, I've been frustrated with the results.

The Unity Launcher doesn't respond on my computer at all, especially when I try to click the Transmission icon. I click it and nothing happens. It randomly happens to other applications as well. It does open when I click on the icon with the right mouse button and choose "Start transmission minimized" though.

Also, the menu is really jumpy and when I click something, it just scrolls up or down and ends up opening something else.

I have been really disappointed with this Unity feature so far and I just want to switch back to my old OS because of it.

Can someone help me? I really want to give Ubuntu 12.04 a chance. But it just seems so wrong.

As far as I recall, this didn't happen before the last update (at least I didn't notice it all THAT much before).

**Also, I have this thing happening to me all the time:**

[image]

And my last issue is that each time I'm **trying to open an external file** (aka: I download a word document from my company's website), it just doesn't open it with the icon that was already in the menu when the OS was installed (I didn't move it and didn't do **anything** with it). It just randomly creates another icon.

As far as I understand, the Unity Launcher is a combined launcher and task bar. So the same icon is used to launch an application and to restore it, in case it in minimised or hidden. Now, when I open an odt file from my browser, by either opening it or saving to my computer and then opening, it doesn't use the LibreOffice Writer icon I already have, but it shows a new, additional LibreOffice Writer icon. Also, clicking the icon I already have closes all instances of Writer.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a combined launcher and taskbar, sounds like your configuration is pretty f-up. Try holding down alt and pressing f2 to open the run dialogue and typing in `unity --reset` before pressing enter. The screen may flicker for a bit, but then things should be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks! That was a working, immediate no-frills solution!

Answer (score 0):

First, file your problem as a bug by holding down Ctrl + Alt + T and then typing in 'ubuntu-bug unity' and following the instructions.

Then, try pressing the 'Super' ('Windows') key, typing in 'Drivers' and hitting 'Enter', then click on the recommended proprietary driver (if you haven't already), click 'Activate' and reboot after it has activated. See if that helps.

It also might be that your computer is struggling to run Unity 3D so you should probably select Ubuntu 2D when you log in by clicking the white circle to the top-right of your name on the log in screen.

If you still can't use Unity (2D), try holding down Ctrl + Alt + T and typing in 'sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop', then (after installing) select Lubuntu when you log in by clicking the white circle to the top-right of your name on the log in screen. Lubuntu gives a more traditional desktop and is VERY lightweight so will almost definitely work on your system.

I don't really get what you mean by the last problem. But if you are opening a word document, you can either:
1. Click on the download in the downloads button in Firefox
2. Click on the Writer button on the Launcher (or hit the 'Super' ('Windows') key and type in 'Writer' and press 'Enter') and then click 'File' > 'Open...' and select your file.
3. Or click on the Home Folder icon (or hit the 'Super' ('Windows') key and type in 'Home' and press 'Enter'), double-click on Downloads and double-click on your file.

Sorry if the above sounds like I'm trying to dumb you down, I'm only trying to make it as clear as possible.

Nice one Handuel, should've thought of that (facepalm)

Comment: The proprietary driver is already installed. I don't think my computer is struggling to run Unity 3D as it runs applications which appear a lot more heavy, like some graphic-intensive games.

About the last issue, the Unity launcher is, so far as I understand, a combined launcher and task bar. When I open an odt file from my browser, by either opening it or saving to my computer and then opening, it doesn't use the LibreOffice Writer icon I already have, but it shows a new, additional Writer icon (second linked image). Clicking the icon I already have closes all instances of Writer.